# Why does a barebones Rails controller block if the database is down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple Rails controller which does not depend on the database.

```
class PingController < ActionController::Base
  def ping
    render text: 'The service is up'
  end
end
```

However, when the database goes down, this controller action blocks. 
Why does this happen?

Comment: IMO this depends on your environment: What server do you use? Are you in `development` or `production` environment? Is the server already running for some time, when you test this behaviour or was the server just started or idleing for a longer period of time?

Comment: I would suggest you to examine your middlewares. One of it might easily use blocking IO to/from database. Please post your middleware stack here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it blocks'? Are you seeing any errors?

Answer (score 2):

I think there could be three culprits.

A fresh Rails application has the following middleware ([Source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html)):

```
use Rack::Sendfile
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x000000029a0838>
use Rack::Runtime
use Rack::MethodOverride
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
use ActionDispatch::Flash
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
run Rails.application.routes
```

Each request to your controller essentially passes through each one of these middlewares in a chain, one after the other.

Three of these are related to the database and thus depend on the database for every request. You'll notice they're all part of `ActiveRecord` which is a big tip-off the database is involved.

1. `ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending`

   This checks if there are pending migrations in the database before passing the request through. From what I can tell looking at the source code it checks for pending migrations in **all environments**.
2. `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement`

   Except in the testing enviornment, this middleware purges active db connections **each request**. Perhaps the database connectivity in this middleware is blocking your controller action.
3. `ActiveRecord::QueryCache`

   This could also be blocking database requests. It is active for all environments from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Rails checks for pending migrations (at least in development mode) before a request. I guess this check blocks your db unrelated action when your database goes down.